# jgit IncorrectObjectTypeException while compare commits

Tags: java, git, github, repository

I have a java program and want to mine a git repository to extract methods signature changes. I want to compare git entry commit differences by java. Therefore, I have used this code:

```
 List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff()
                                .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                                .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                                .call();

                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(out);
                        df.setRepository(git.getRepository());

                        for(DiffEntry diff : diffs)
                        {
                            df.format(diff);
                            diff.getOldId();                          


    if(diff.getNewPath().endsWith(".java") && diff.getChangeType()== DiffEntry.ChangeType.MODIFY){
modifyItems=difN.getDiffs(diff.getOldId().name(),diff.getNewId().name());
}
```

Here it is getDiff method which tries to compare two commits based on their id:

```
 Repository repo = new FileRepository("xxx.git");
        Git git = new Git(repo);
        ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();


        ObjectId headId = git.getRepository().resolve(headIdStr);
        ObjectId oldId = git.getRepository().resolve(oldIdStr);

        CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        oldTreeIter.reset(reader, oldId);
        CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        newTreeIter.reset(reader, headId);

        List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff()
                .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                .call();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(out);
        df.setRepository(git.getRepository());

        for(DiffEntry diff : diffs)
        {
            df.format(diff);
            diff.getOldId();
            String diffText = out.toString("UTF-8");
            out.reset();
        }
        return diffs;
```

I try to compare this commit with its previous one but I am not sure if this code is correct or not. moreover, as long as I run this code this error happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object e973f7fea67fd355623e1df75b0c756004afa55f is not a tree.
```